# Debugging custom module - content not displaying

Tags: module, magento-1, blocks, debugging

I am practicing Magento, So I develop a new custom module . The module is working fine but I have a problem with my layout file. This is what i have got in my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<layout >


    <ias_myslideshow_index_index>

        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="ias/myslideshow_slideshow" name="ias.myslideshow.slideshow" template="IAS/slideshow.phtml" output="toHtml" />
        </reference>

    </ias_myslideshow_index_index>



</layout>
```

In the block type if I write

```
block type="core/template"
```

Then every static content that I have written in the pthml is displayed but if I try to call a function written in my block it throws an error for not finding the method. If I change  block type to

```
block type="ias/myslideshow_slideshow"

             OR

block type="ias/slideshow"
```

Nothing is display. No static content, no error.

I will really appreciate if some one can let me know what the wrong I am doing. below is my block and config file

```
public function myMessage(){

    return “I am Iyngaran, This is my module.”;

}
```

}

```
    public function myMessage(){

        return “I am Iyngaran, This is my module.”;

    }
}


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <IAS_MySlideshow>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </IAS_MySlideshow>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <helpers>
        <IAS_MySlideshow>
            <class>IAS_MySlideshow_Helper</class>
        </IAS_MySlideshow>
    </helpers>


        <blocks>
            <IAS_MySlideshow>
                <class>IAS_MySlideshow_Block</class>
            </IAS_MySlideshow>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <IAS_MySlideshow>
                <resourceModel>ias_myslideshow_resource</resourceModel>
            </IAS_MySlideshow>

            <ias_myslideshow_resource>
                <entities>
                    <slideshow>
                        <table>ias_myslideshow_slideshow</table>
                    </slideshow>
                </entities>
            </ias_myslideshow_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <myslideshow_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>IAS_MySlideshow</module>
                </setup>
            </myslideshow_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <IAS_MySlideshow>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>IAS_MySlideshow</module>
                    <frontName>slideshow</frontName>
                </args>
            </IAS_MySlideshow>
        </routers>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <IAS_MySlideshow>
                    <!--this file name can be any name-->
                    <file>slide-show.xml</file>
                </IAS_MySlideshow>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <IAS_MySlideshow before="Mage_Adminhtml">IAS_MySlideshow_Adminhtml</IAS_MySlideshow>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
    </admin>


</config>
```

Comment: Please try with `IAS_MySlideshow/nameoftheblock` (replace nameoftheblock with your block name).

Comment: please see at  http://www.amitbera.com/create-an-magento-extension-with-custom-database-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to write below in block type if your module name is myslideshow and the file placed in block folder is slideshow.php because in magento block type "modulename/blockfilename"

```
"myslideshow/slideshow"
```

For above magento find block file in below path:

```
"myslideshow/block/slideshow.php"
```

Comment: Appreciate Hardik. I have resolved that. It was problem with my config file in etc directory

Thanks a lot :)